# wpf and c# writeable datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

I want to make a DataGridView sheet that can allow a user to input data.

Below is my xaml code for my datagrid

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
    Height="710" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Name="flowgrid" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="1000" Margin="181,91,0,0" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged">

    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account Details" 
            x:Name="value1" IsReadOnly="True"   MinWidth="180" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Due Date"   MinWidth="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Standard Amount"   MinWidth="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Current"   MinWidth="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Week 1"  MinWidth="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Week 2"  MinWidth="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Week 3"  MinWidth="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Week 4"  MinWidth="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="After"  MinWidth="150" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: What's your problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Gareth , the problem is if i try to input data into a cell the app is going in break mode and am having this error..'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.

Comment: How do you fill the DataGrid with items?

Comment: @mm8 I'm new to wpf, your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @mm8 yes thank you so much , now working on it

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `IsReadOnly` property of the cells you want the user to edit (or of the whole DataGrid) to `False`:

```
IsReadOnly="False"
```

Also, if you want to let the user add new rows, you can set the `CanUserAddRows` property to `True`:

```
CanUserAddRows="True"
```

To input the data into the dataGrid I do it like this:
1- Empty the dataGrid in the xaml file:
2- Create a Datatable object with the headers and the data
3- set it like ItemSource of the datagrid

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid"></DataGrid>
```

VB:

```
Dim inputDataDB As DataTable
inputDataDB = getInputData()

dataGrid.ItemsSource = inputDataDB .DefaultView
```

Hope it Help

Comment: Thanks, let me try to do so

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried that but if I input data the application is going into break mode. I don't know if you can help

Answer (score 0):

For you to be able to edit items in a `DataGrid`, you need to set its `ItemsSource` property to an `IList`.

You cannot add items directly to the `Items` property like this:

```
flowgrid.Items.Add(new Account());
```

Instead you should set the `ItemsSource` property:

```
flowgrid.ItemsSource = new List<Acccount>() { ... };
```